# What is the correct dataURL including filters for sapui5 spreadsheet control

Tags: sapui5, spreadsheet

I am using the export to spreadsheet control in SAPUI5 (    "sap/ui/export/Spreadsheet" described under https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet). 
When calling the odata Service without filters it works fine. When adding filters I get an 'uncaught in promise Unexpected Server Response' error in the frontend. What is the correct Url including filters that I have to specify under dataUrl?

Thank you for the help!

Christophe

So far I am trying with:
dataUrl: "/sap/opu/odata/sap//?$filter=Export eq 'X'"

```
oSettings = {
    workbook: {
        columns: aCols,
        hierarchyLevel: "Level",
    },
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        dataUrl: "/sap/opu/odata/sap/<myService>/<myEntitySet>?$filter=Export eq 'X'", 
        serviceUrl: oModelInterface.sServiceUrl,  
        headers: oModelInterface.getHeaders ? oModelInterface.getHeaders() : null,
        count: oBinding.getLength ? oBinding.getLength() : null,
        useBatch: true,
        sizeLimit: oModelInterface.iSizeLimit
    },
    worker: false,
};

var oSpreadsheet = new Spreadsheet(oSettings);
oSpreadsheet.build();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for the download URL.
Just use oBinding.getDownloadUrl()

Just to be safe:

```js
dataUrl: oRowBinding.getDownloadUrl ? oRowBinding.getDownloadUrl() : null
```

Reference: [https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataListBinding/methods/getDownloadUrl)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if you want to another filter parameter? How would you do that?

Comment: @Cruncher, add the filter to the binding (binding.filter([<filters>])) and then use getDownloadUrl()